# UIAlert suddenly stopped working?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

My code used to work fine, but for some reason running it today, it did a different task. I am basically trying to show an alert if the user is having a short username, email or password or else will give an alert the registration is complete and THEN move to the next view. However now, as soon as I click submit it goes to the next view ignoring the alerts. Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {        
    // Validate the text fields
    if username!.count < 5 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater than 5 characters", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    } else if password!.count < 8 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid", message: "Password must be greater than 7 characters", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if email!.count < 8 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid", message: "Email must be greater than 7 characters", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Account has been created, an email will be sent shortly", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
            action in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpDone", sender: self)
        })
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have a segue "signUpDone" in the handle which tells it only to move on to next view of complete. But for some reason it ignores all the if statements and just goes to next view without a single alert of conditions or successful alert. I get a console information that says "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

I haven't touched the code, but weirdly this happens when I try to run it today. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the segue was connected directly from the button to the view instead of view to view, which forced the button to immediately go to the view disregarding the if statements!